# Pop Up credentials frequently for Outlook

Tags: exchange-2010

When the first time user has key-in the password, the Outlook is connected to Microsoft Exchange, then later it will pop up again and asking for password for several times. So this is very irritating for the user. This happens when the desktop/laptop is not joined to the domain. If the desktop/Laptop has joined the domain, there is no problem. FYI, the Exchange version is Exchange 2010 SP2. Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Have you looked at the "related questions" such as https://serverfault.com/q/171388/102173 ?

Comment: Check “remember my credentials.”

Comment: I am using just basic authentication rather than NTLM authentication.

Comment: What if you set Outlook to run as a domain user rather than a local user.

Comment: Yup, it is run as a domain user rather than the local user.

Comment: I have checked that the Outlook Anywhere configuration is disabled. Is it a must to configure Outlook Anywhere? Thanks.